# mysql: how to get the last value of one spesific column as part of the subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

```
+--------------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| StopAddress        | UserID | Name | StartHours | EndHours | SamplingEnd         |
+--------------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| Legends            |      1 | Lisa | 09:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 09:00:00 |
| 26 Bluewater Drive |      1 | Lisa | 10:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 10:00:00 |
| Walker Drive       |      1 | Lisa | 11:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 11:00:00 |
| Blouberg           |      1 | Lisa | 12:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 12:00:00 |
| William Moffet     |      1 | Lisa | 13:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 13:00:00 |
| Paterson           |      1 | Lisa | 14:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 14:00:00 |
| 70 Kings Street    |      1 | Lisa | 15:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 15:00:00 |
| Pick n Pay         |      1 | Lisa | 16:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 16:00:00 |
| Mars               |      1 | Lisa | 17:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 17:00:00 |
| Club Shakes        |      1 | Lisa | 18:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 18:00:00 |
| Stones             |      1 | Lisa | 19:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 19:00:00 |
| Ermelo             |      1 | Lisa | 20:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 20:00:00 |
| Angelos            |      1 | Lisa | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 05:00:00 |
| Game               |      1 | Lisa | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 04:00:00 |
+--------------------+--------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

When I run the following query, I get the result below. (See "Current result" )

QUERY:

```
SELECT Min(samplingend) AS StartTime, 
       Min(starthours)  AS StartHours, 
       Max(endhours)    AS EndHours, 
       Max(samplingend) AS LastStart, 
       (SELECT stopaddress 
        FROM   table1 
        ORDER  BY samplingend DESC 
        LIMIT  1)       AS StopAddress 
FROM   table1 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          name, 
          Date(samplingend) 
ORDER  BY Date(samplingend), 
          userid;
```

CURRENT RESULT:

```
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
 | StartTime           | StartHours | EndHours | LastStart           | StopAddress |
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
 | 2016-03-22 09:00:00 | 09:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 20:00:00 | Angelos     |
 | 2016-03-23 04:00:00 | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 05:00:00 | Angelos     |
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

DESIRED RESULT:
When you run the query it must give the StopAddress WHERE StopAddress = Max(SamplingEnd) grouped per day. 
e.g.  On the 22nd StopAddress should = "Ermelo" and on the 23rd = Angelos in the example below. Is it possible to achieve this result by altering the code ONLY in LINE6 WITHOUT USING Table Aliases. e.g by not using table1 T1 or T2?  
 
  Line 6:   (SELECT StopAddress from table1 order by SamplingEnd DESC limit 1) AS StopAddress)

Example of outcome: (Look at the StopAddress Column)

```
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
 | StartTime           | StartHours | EndHours | LastStart           | StopAddress |
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
 | 2016-03-22 09:00:00 | 09:00:00   | 08:00:59 | 2016-03-22 20:00:00 | Ermelo     |
 | 2016-03-23 04:00:00 | 05:00:00   | 00:20:16 | 2016-03-23 05:00:00 | Angelos     |
 +---------------------+------------+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include table alias to use the external value

```
SELECT Min(samplingend) AS StartTime, 
       Min(starthours)  AS StartHours, 
       Max(endhours)    AS EndHours, 
       Max(samplingend) AS LastStart, 
       (SELECT T2.stopaddress 
        FROM   table1  T2
        WHERE  Date(T2.samplingend) = Date(T1.samplingend) -- ADD THIS WHERE
        ORDER  BY T2.samplingend DESC 
        LIMIT  1)       AS StopAddress 
FROM   table1  T1
GROUP  BY userid, 
          name, 
          Date(samplingend) 
ORDER  BY Date(samplingend), 
          userid;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, it works when I run the query in the mysql terminal with the given example, but I need it for 3rd party software. It looks like the 3rd party software doesn't want me to use table aliases. Is there a way to do this without using table aliases. not sure if I'm using the right terminology, e.g T1 and T2. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: well you can remove the alias and write the full name, but I doubt a third party is causing you those problems,. What tool is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT StartTime, StartHours, EndHours, LastStart,
      (SELECT StopAddress 
       FROM table1 AS t2 
       WHERE t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND 
             t1.Name = t2.Name AND 
             t2.SamplingEnd = t1.LastStart
       LIMIT 1) AS StopAddress     
FROM (
  SELECT UserID, Name,
         MIN(SamplingEnd) AS StartTime,
         MIN(StartHours) AS StartHours,
         MAX(EndHours) AS EndHours,
         MAX(SamplingEnd) AS LastStart   
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY UserID, Name, DATE(SamplingEnd)) AS t1
```

The idea is to wrap your query in  subquery and in the outer query use a correlated subquery using the value of `LastStart` in order to get the `StopAddress`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae256e/2)

Comment: Ok Thanks, it works when I run the query in the mysql terminal with the given example, but I need it for 3rd party software. It looks like the 3rd party software doesn't want me to use table aliases. Is there a way to do this without using table aliases. not sure if I'm using the right terminology, e.g T1 and T2. I will edit the post accordingly.